# mongodb project count number of sizes objects with condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello I have a posts collection in mongodb where there's an authors field and when I run the following command:

```js
db.posts.aggregate( [ {$project:{ size: {$size: {$ifNull:["$authors", []] }}}} ] )
```

I get a result like that:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c917fe48ad625ee8f49714"), "size" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c91b83895efc5f0f67ba1a"), "size" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c91cfd2971c05f310fccb8"), "size" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c91eb7a826965f85571656"), "size" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c921a1cb2bc85fa77e593a"), "size" : 30 }
```

How can I count the number of times when size is not equal to 0?
So in that case the result would be 4.

I tried "db.posts.aggregate( [ {$project:{ size: {$size: {$not:{"$authors": 0} }}}} ] )
"  with no success...

Comment: You can use regular query. `db.posts.count({"authors":{ $exists:true, $ne:[] } })`

Comment: This worked buddy

Answer (score 0):

You want to use $match and $count aggregation methods, something like the below. See more [MongoDB Aggregate $count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)

```
 db.posts.aggregate( 
   [ {
     $match:{ size: {$gt: 0}}
   }, {
    $count:'total'
   } ] )
```

This should return something like:

```
 { "total" : 4 }
```

Comment: I'm not getting anything, where's the authors field?

Comment: Assuming you have some authorId in the data structure you could do something like:

db.posts.aggregate( 
   [ {
     $match:{ size: {$gt: 0}}
   },{
    $group: {
     _id: '$authorId'
   }, {
    $count:'total'
   } ] )

Which will then group the results by authorId. If you are wanting the entire post object to be returned with the aggregate you are going to have to do something different. I dont know what your data looks like so you are going to have to figure out how to make this example fit your data.

Comment: No, this doesn't work, I don't want to group them by id